# Select k elements from a weighted stream of elements

Tags: algorithm, statistics, genetic-algorithm

I need an algorithm to select `K` elements from an array of length `N`. Since `N` can be a very large number, the algorithm should work with a steamed collection. To be more concrete, this is how the collection looks: `[(el1, 1000), (el2, 500), ...., (elN, 230)]`. Elements with higher weights should have more chances to get into the resulting array.

I did some research and found a paper [WEIGHTED RESERVOIR SAMPLING](https://developer.download.nvidia.com//ray-tracing-gems/rtg2-chapter22-preprint.pdf?hTm0fnZY_P47IFyEfJsMD1fSVDt0Z9quMHXDC2uI4DrmUjIhHLJ2gIkTdfDWGkEVSUobEs4UR5BcmHKTsvJYx76RSjNLF3swE9Yr4rVgIoGkUlQuz3mBw8xbXwxyMQZQ34qXYvbbjB2Cux4-). It seems to be a good solution and it does what I need.

However, I also read about [Fitness proportionate selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection), which seems like it solves the problem too.

I struggle to understand the difference between them and which one should I choose?

Comment: I fail to see how Fitness Proportionate selection solves the problem, as you would need the total weight of all elements of the stream.

Comment: With replacement or without?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, but it's possible to have the total weight of all elements. We store the collection in the database, so we can accumulate the total weight.

Comment: I think I need it without replacement. It's something like a lottery, where people get tickets, and at the end, they get `K` prizes (one person can get only one prize). For those who have more tickets, there are more chances to win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither one of those algorithms handles without-replacement sampling without modification.

If you want to simulate the manual process of drawing tickets until there are k distinct winners, then you can assign each element e a key −log1p(−random())/weight(e) where random() returns a uniform random double-precision floating point number between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive, i.e., an [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) random variate with rate weight(e), and choose the k elements with the smallest keys in a streaming fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm wondering if algorithm from this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Weighted_random_sampling would work? `Algorithm A-Chao` seems to describe sampling without replacement. Or the more concrete question, how good is it at simulating drawing winners?

Comment: It's not a complete algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I have coded your approach and it seems to work fine. However the same with `random(0, 1)/weight` seems to show similar results. Can you please describe what role `log1p` is playing here? Or maybe any references to this approach?

Comment: @Ivan it's equivalent to A-Res from the Wikipedia link, but with better numerical properties wrt machine floating-point. It simulates the physical process of drawing entry slips, whereas random(0,1)/weight does not. Both satisfy your criterion of sampling heavy items with greater probability, however.